# Para que servem os escondidos __makeref e __refvalue?

Tags: c#

Neste pequeno código, consigo fazer a função de referências com:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int x = 0;
        AlterNumber(__makeref(x));
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
    
    static void AlterNumber(TypedReference n) {
        __refvalue(n, int) = 10;
    }
}
```

Mas o ponto interessante é que eu consigo portar essa referência como o próprio valor, e para obter seu valor eu utilizo `__refvalue`.

Estas duas funções não são documentadas nem estão na especificação da linguagem. Tem outras também, mas no momento vou focar apenas nestas duas.

Por que elas existem? Por que não foram documentadas e por que devo evitar usá-las?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__makeref` e `__refvalue` são tecnicamente [palavras chaves não documentadas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4773964/6054186) da linguagem, que [funcionam como funções globais](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/low-level-struct-improvements#sunset-restricted-types). Elas fazem parte de um conjunto maior (juntamente com `__arglist` e `__reftype`), principalmente [utilizadas no contexto de integrar dados do runtime do .Net com código nativo, principalmente C e C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1712038/6054186) . Essa é a razão pela qual elas existem.

Essas palavras chaves basicamente operam com o struct [`TypedReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.typedreference?view=net-7.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN). Observe na página linkada da documentação do .Net que o `TypedReference` não é "CLS-compliant", significando que não há garantias que ele vai funcionar corretamente (ou sequer existir) em todas as linguagens do .Net suporta. Isto responde a sua questão sobre porque *não* utilizá-las normalmente.

Havia até algum uso "normal" para elas *antes* da criação do modificador [`ref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref), pois `__makeref` e `__refvalue` permitiam, por exemplo, mexer num tipo por valor a distância, por referência, algo que até então exigiria a criação de um tipo específico ou do [boxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) automático. A passagem e retorno por referência utilizando `ref` é muito mais clara e melhor suportada no .Net.

`ref` não é só mais claro como é potencialmente [muito mais rápido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133859/get-a-reference-to-a-struct-inside-array/14277068#14277068) que utilizar `__makeref` e `__refvalue`, relegando essas "funções" somente para integração com código nativo.

Comment: Você explicou porque não é interessante usar elas, mas não explicou bem porque não são documentadas nem também para o que elas servem. Poderia fornecer estes detalhes?

Comment: Acrescentei links detalhando a não documentação provavelmente intencional, assim como a razão específica qual elas ainda são utilizadas.